# How to configure Windows Azure as an Identity Provider with Oauth 2.0

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I want to use Azure as an identity provider for a third party service provider(SP). My question is

1. How can I generate the client ID and Client secret with respect to the SP. (Please note that my SP is not an application, but another IDP which will be an SP to Azure since the scenario I'm try out is Multi Factor Authentication )

   webapp ----> Third party IDP(Acts as a SP to Azure) ------> Windows Azure
2. How can I get the public key of Azure?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If all you desire is to signin a Azure AD user to your web app, you don't need OAuth: you need to configure web single-signon between your web app and the intermediate IdP and between the intermediate IdP and Azure AD. At your app, the user's browser will be redirected to the intermediate IdP and then to Azure AD. The user will authenticate at Azure AD. You can turn on MFA for the user in Azure AD - this will be enforced at authentication. Post successful auth,an authentication response will be sent back to the intermediate IdP and it will send an authentication response to your web app. For Web SSO you can either use SAML or WSFed (depending on what your intermediate IdP supports.)

You will need to configure your intermediate IdP as an SP in Azure AD. If you haven't already, signup for Azure. Signin to the management portal, and go the Active Directory tab on the left. Select the directory and go to the applications tab. This is where you should register a new app representing the SP (your intermediate IdP). The following properties of the app are important:

- App ID URI: this should match the Issuer of the SSO request that your intermediate IdP sends to Azure AD
- Reply URL: this is the URL where Azure AD will post the authentication response. Your intermediate IdP should listen for authentication responses at this URL.

Next you will need to configure Azure AD as an IdP in your intermediate IdP. All the data required to configure this is in Azure AD's federation metadata document. While on the configure application page in Azure management portal, click on the View Endpoints button in the bottom bar to get the Federation Metadata Document URL of your Azure AD (https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml).

If you do indeed need to use OAuth with Azure AD: on the application configuration page you will find the Client ID of the app (a Guid value). You can generate a key (valid for 1 or 2 years) - this will serve as the Client Secret.

Here's some help topics that will see your through:

- Authentication scenarios (when to use SAML/WSFed/OAuth/OpenIDConnect): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx
- Registering an application with Azure AD: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn132599.aspx
- Azure AD federation metadata: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195592.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate your response Dushyant.I configured Azure with the intermediate IDP and the below error is seen in the intermediate IDP console. "invalid_request, ACS50001: The required field 'resource' is missing". In order for the intermediate IDP to trust azure we need to add Azure public key to be imported in the IDP. But that can't be located.

Comment: Federation metadata document that I referred to above has the token signing public key of Azure AD: https://login.windows.net/{your_tenant_id}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml. However the error seems to be a different issue. Can you describe how you configured the trust with Azure AD - it seems you're using OAuth - for SSO you don't need OAuth - SAML or WSFed should do

Comment: Created a namespace in Azure AD and then created an application registering SP (intermediate IDP)